# C# app hangs after publish

Tags: c#, odp.net, odac

I have an app that uses ODP.net. it runs in visual studio debug. when I publish it to the same PC, I run setup.exe and it installs, starts and runs fine. When I go to the exe and start it from there it hangs. I commented out the calls to the oracle methods, republished and it runs. I know I included the dll. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "hangs" part? Does it hang indefinitely, or just during some timeout? Any error messages?

Comment: Have you tried installing your application, then in VS, set your installed .exe as the "run this program and attach VS to the process" target, in the project's properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install some native libraries too.
Follow the instructions at [this blog post](http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2010/01/odpnet-minimal-non-intrusive-install.html) or find the official Oracle documentation.

Comment: I can run the app from my debug\bin folder or the installed location without doing the above. I have discovered that if I try to run an ODP.NET method first it hangs. If I run a ADO.NET method first then an ODP.NET method it works. They are in two unrelated classes. Totally bizaar. Within VS debug it works either way.

Comment: Looking further, it seems to work fine on my other computer. No issues at all. I wonder if it is a security setting.